# Why am I getting a org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException exception?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, firefox

Yesterday I used Eclipse to run a Java program that used the Selenium API and Firefox as the browser. Today I made some modifications to the program and, when I try to run it, I get:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
```

followed by many more lines of text.

This is thrown by the first line of code that is executed in the program. I have made no changes to versions of Eclipse or Firefox, and the Selenium build path for the program is the same. So why is the exception thrown?

Comment: I would test rolling back all the changes, verify you don't get the exception, then incrementally add back the changes and try to pinpoint where it breaks. You should also post the line of code where you are getting the exception and add a few more lines of the stack trace.

Comment: Thank you Michael Markidis. Your comments got me thinking about what changes have been made since yesterday. Yes I've changed the program, but then other programs that I hadn't changed ran. Then I checked Firefox's versions and it turns out that the latest version is only 4 days old. My Firefox version was indeed the latest, so I installed the previous version and the program now runs fine. Ahrg that silent Firefox update!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't open browser with selenium after firefox update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761668/cant-open-browser-with-selenium-after-firefox-update)