# Springboot selenium and firefox

Tags: selenium, spring-boot

I am using IntelliJ. using Springboot with Selenium and Junit.

I am trying to test my webpage with Firefox driver.

It worked fine few weeks ago and have feeling new version of firefox causing this problem.

FF v. 47
selenium-java v. 2.25.0

When i try to run my Selenium test cases i am getting following exception

```
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
-a285-3208198ce6fd}","syncGUID":"6zcAb79-4SXm","location":"app-global","version":"47.0.1","type":"theme","internalName":"classic/1.0","updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{"32":"icon.png","48":"icon.png"},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Default","description":"The default theme.","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla Contributors"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","installDate":1467133440000,"updateDate":1467133440000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":7140,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"47.0.1","maxVersion":"47.0.1"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"seen":true}
1467133725784   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1467133725786   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1467133725786   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1467133725786   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1467133725787   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1467133725789   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1467133725790   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.0
1467133725790   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1467133725791   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.2
1467133725793   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1467133725793   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.3.2
1467133725831   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1467133725831   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1467133725831   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1467133725831   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1467133725832   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1467133725832   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1467133725846   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1467133725846   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1467133725846   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1467133725846   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1467133725847   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1467133725847   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1467133726445   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1467133726456   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1467133726456   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1467133726456   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1467133726708   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1467133726711   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1467133726717   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1467133726771   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1467133726771   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1467133726772   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1467133726777   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1467133726777   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
1467133726778   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1467133726809   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at net.xeric.demos.TestConfig.getWebDriver(TestConfig.java:17)
    at net.xeric.demos.TestConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dbbd9da2.CGLIB$getWebDriver$0(<generated>)
    at net.xeric.demos.TestConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dbbd9da2$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$26cf5163.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:355)
    at net.xeric.demos.TestConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dbbd9da2.getWebDriver(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:183)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox 47.0, selenium selenium-java-2.53.0 windows64 org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805856/firefox-47-0-selenium-selenium-java-2-53-0-windows64-org-openqa-selenium-remote)

Comment: It might not look like the same question but the answer should be the same as for your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't open browser with Selenium after Firefox update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761668/cant-open-browser-with-selenium-after-firefox-update)

Answer (score 0):

downgraded FF 47 to 46 and worked for me.