# Selenenium error: WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, linux-mint, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am attempting to get Selenium to work on my Linux mint installation. In the Python3 terminal, I type:

```
from selenium import webdriver
firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
```

The second line immediately gives me the following error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

I thought it may be an old version of selenium, so I ran:

```
pip3 install selenium --upgrade
```

It confirms that Selenium is up to date. I'm using Linux Mint, so I ran apt-get to see if there is an upgrade for Firefox. There isn't. Restarted and tried selenium again at the Python command line, same error.

I'm running Python 3.4, Linux Mint 17.2 (32-bit), Firefox 47.0, selenium 2.53.5. Is this just an incompatibility between selenium and Firefox, or should I be looking somewhere else to figure it out?

Comment: Selenium 2.53.5 doesn't support Firefox 47. Downgrade Firefox or use the marionette driver (geckodriver).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't open browser with selenium after firefox update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761668/cant-open-browser-with-selenium-after-firefox-update)

Comment: @FlorentB. You're right. Looks like the marionette driver won't work with python 3, though, so I'm switching over to Chrome.