# Driver Error in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I got a below error, If I start execute the program.

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not
>   start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote
>   server or browser start-up failure. Build info: version: '2.53.0',
>   revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: I'm using Version 47.0

Comment: Start from version 47.0 you will need to use the MarionetteDriver if you plan on using Firefox. Look at the answer to this question for a detailed explanation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761668/cant-open-browser-with-selenium-after-firefox-update/37765661#37765661

Comment: now I got the below error.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/jgraham/wires. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/jgraham/wires

Comment: As the answer I linked stated you need to: "Download the driver, rename it to wires.exe and make sure the executable is present in your system path". The driver can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Comment: Still the same issue remains, After downloaded and refer

Comment: For chrome driver also getting the below error.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Comment: For chromdriver you'll need a different driver. The error says it cannot find the executable in your path. How did you set it? Are you using windows?

Comment: I'm using windows 64 bits and already downloaded chromedriver32 and refer

Comment: What do you mean by "and refer"? You didn't answer my question on how you added the driver to the PATH variable.

Comment: Refer means I added into the "Referenced libraries"

Comment: That won't do. You need to add the path to wires.exe to your PATH system variable. See https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml on how to do this

Answer (score 0):

The problem is stemming from the novel engine of Firefox after version 47.
I fixed this problem by uninstalling latest Firefox and installing the older one (version: 45.x.x.).

You can download it from [firefox older releases](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/45.0.1/win64-EME-free/en-US/%20link) directory.