# Unable to open browser with specified URL using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Unable to open firefox browser with specified url in selenium webdriver. Only the browser is opening without the url.

Firefox version is 47.
Selenium version is 2.53.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't open browser with selenium after firefox update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761668/cant-open-browser-with-selenium-after-firefox-update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to solve your problem.

1- You can downgrade your `firefox` by reinstalling and select `Never check for updates (not recommended: security risk)` in your `firefox` by nevigate through

**Open Menu->Options->Advanced**.

2- if you want to working with current version of `firefox` which is `47` you should try with `MarionetteDriver`...by following [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver)

If you have any problem with this let me know...:)

Comment: Thank you for solution. It helped :)