# Cannot invoke any Web Browser with WebDriver using Eclipse IDE (Mars 2.0)

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to execute a login code using WebDriver but I am unable to invoke any Web Browser.

[image]

Comment: are you getting any error log.. post your full error log also

Comment: your firefox version seems latest... you need to follow this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836121/unable-to-open-browser-with-specified-url-using-selenium-webdriver/37836314#37836314

Comment: Thank you very much.. Downgrading worked for me..