# Browser not launching for selenium web driver in Intranet

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I have tried to launch firefox browser with selenium webdriver in my office intranet connection .
getting error message:

***Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.***

[![Selenium webdriver error message ][2]][2]

Could anyone please help me in this regards.

Comment: have you google for this problem?? there are multiple solution for this.

Comment: Possible cause is invalid address of the remote server

Comment: If your firefox version is 47 you need to downgrade it.. follow link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836121/unable-to-open-browser-with-specified-url-using-selenium-webdriver/37836314#37836314

Comment: Downgrading is not a permanent solution. See one of the other multitude of duplicates already on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off automatic updates for your Firefox.
1- Select the “Menu” button in the upper-right corner, then choose “Options“.
2- Select “Advanced“.
3- Choose the “Update” tab.
4- Select one of the following options as desired: Automatically install updates.

Uninstall your firefox.
Install firefox 46.0.1
http://filehippo.com/download_firefox/67737/

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses.