# Firefox has stopped working while executing the cucumber feature file

Tags: selenium, cucumber, automated-tests

Firefox stopped at the time of executing my simple cucumber feature file.

## Here is my feature file-

### Feature:

As a User
I want to be able to login into the MAX app
So that I can able to see my jobs

### Scenario:

- Given the user is on the Login Page
- When he chooses to Login
- And he provides the Username as ab51208
- And he provides the Password as ab51208
- And he clicks login
- Then he should be able to Login into the MAX app

### Runner Class

```
package com.Runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

 @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
 @CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/java/com.feature/"})
 public class CucumberRunner {

 }
```

## Logs-

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error
> communicating with the remote browser. It may have died. Build info:
> version: '2.41.0', revision:
> '3192d8a6c4449dc285928ba024779344f5423c58', time: '2014-03-27
> 11:29:39' System info: host: 'XIN009CDAB51208', ip: '10.140.49.170',
> os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1',
> java.version: '1.7.0_07' Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

Comment: which firefox version are you using?

Comment: Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836121/unable-to-open-browser-with-specified-url-using-selenium-webdriver/37836314#37836314

Comment: Vesion-47.0.1

And more thing when I launch the Firefox manually I mean without running any script then it's working fine.