# firefox 47.0 browser incompatibility with selenium 2.53.0

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, firefox-47

Is there any stable solution for firefox 47.0 browser incompatibility with selenium 2.53.0 without downgrading firefox into an older version.

Comment: Have you google for it???.. there are multiple solution...have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836121/unable-to-open-browser-with-specified-url-using-selenium-webdriver/37836314#37836314

Comment: The answer is no. There will always be a lag between the last browser version and Selenium support.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade Firefox to 47.0.1 and selenium to 2.53.1.This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade to Firefox 47.0.1.

Firefox 47 crashing with selenium webdriver has been fixed in 47.0.1 as per the release notes - https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/47.0.1/releasenotes/.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :) I have tried even with 47.0.1 but it is not worked for me.