# MarionetteDriver Opens browser and hangs but does not error out

Tags: selenium, firefox, automation, firefox-marionette

This is the only output I get when I run the tests. Do I need to add the geckodriver.exe somewhere in my build path or linked resources?

Console Output:

```
Jun 16, 2016 4:17:38 PM io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.BrowserManager getLatest
INFO: Latest version of [wires, geckodriver] is 0.8.0
C:\Users\aconte/.m2/repository/webdriver/geckodriver\0.8.0/geckodriver-v0.8.0-win32.zip
Jun 16, 2016 4:17:38 PM io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.BrowserManager exportDriver
INFO: Exporting webdriver.gecko.driver as C:\Users\aconte\.m2\repository\webdriver\geckodriver\win32\0.8.0\geckodriver.exe
<- |50:{"applicationType":"gecko","marionetteProtocol":3}|
54:{"name":"getMarionetteID","to":"root","parameters":{}}
```

This my code for setting up the driver.

```
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
            ffprofile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);
            ffprofile.setPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required", false);
            driver = new MarionetteDriver(ffprofile);
```

Comment: You need to add it to your system path, and MarionetteDriver is deprecated. The correct way is to set a capabilities flag on the FirefoxDriver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't open browser with selenium after firefox update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761668/cant-open-browser-with-selenium-after-firefox-update)

Comment: I am able to load the browser and the Firefox WebDriver shows up in the extensions however it is disabled because of the new add-on signing. I used to get around this by creating a Firefox profile and passing that to the FirefoxDriver but when I add the profile I can't connect to the browser and I get the error "Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms"

Comment: You need the Marionette driver to get around the add-on signing. See my linked answer.

Comment: I don't see anything regarding add-on signing in the link. The only code I got from that link is this 
`DesiredCapabilities ffCap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
ffCap.setCapability("marionette", true);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffCap);`

Comment: There isn't anything in there about addon signing in that link no, but Mozilla is turning forcing add on signing on in Firefox 48, making the old driver not work anymore. Only marionette can connect to it then.

Comment: Yeah it's still not working I'm not sure if it's the executable not being added correctly or what. I'll keep trying everything.