# Selenium API Script is failing file running on java

Tags: selenium, firefox, webdriver

I am getting *error message* for it failure while running below script:

```
public class Sample1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.cleartrip.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error mesage you get when you run this? Without this we cannot help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't open browser with selenium after firefox update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761668/cant-open-browser-with-selenium-after-firefox-update)

Answer (score 0):

Your Firefox browser might not been installed on default location. Try using below code.

```
public class Sample1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver", "location of your firefox exe");    
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.cleartrip.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

}

Thanks,

Rakesh Raut