# Why do my Selenium Spectrum Tests run twice?

Tags: selenium, visual-studio-2015, test-explorer

Whenever I run a feature test from Visual Studio 2015 Test Explorer, FireFox starts up, goes through the Steps, the browser shuts down, I get either a pass or fail.  Then the test starts all over, the browser opens, goes through the Steps...

What could be doing this?

The other thing is that in the output window I see:

```
"NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 executing tests is started"
```

It does it's thing.
Then

```
"NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 executing tests is finished
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 executing tests is started"
```

So there are two instances of the NUnit VS Adaptor 2.0.
I just can't find the second one.

Everyone says go into "Tools -> Extensions and Updates" and delete "NUnit.VisualStudio.TestAdapter" it from there.
But I don't even see it there.

Also I deleted "NUnit.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.dll" from the references of my features test project and an automation class library it references.
So now I don't know how it's even running at all.
I really need to solve this.

So that should just leave one version of NUnit.

---

Here is the architecture of the solution:

1) We have the main project that is an MVC/Web API project. No references of course to NUNit here.

2) A Testing/Functional project folder. ( there are other folders under Testing like Performance and Unit. So we have Unit testing, Performance testing and Functional Testing all under the Testing folder.
So zeroing in on the Testing/Functional project folder for Selenium:

a) We have an Automation C# class library.  This is where a lot of the Spectrum Driver setup happens I think.

This references:

nunit.core - Runtime version: v2.0.50727 - Version: 2.6.4.14350

nunit.core.interfaces - Runtime version: v2.0.50727 - Version: 2.6.4.14350

nunit.framework - Runtime version: v2.0.50727 - Version: 2.6.4.14350

nunit.util - Runtime version: v2.0.50727 - Version: 2.6.4.14350

SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic - Runtime version: v4.0.30319 - Version: 1.1.0.0

b) The actual EndToEndTests feature testing project.
This references the automation project mentioned above plus all the other same dlls that the automation project references.  Keep in mind I deleted "NUnit VS Adaptor.dll" from both.

---

Firefox version: 47.0.1

Just now updated to: 48.0

---

This morning, after the FireFox upgrade, in the output window I get:

SetUp failed for test fixture SetUp : OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Failed to start up socket within 45000 ms. Attempted to connect to the following addresses: 127.0.0.1:7055

Now really stuck on this part.
I have updated all Selenium, Spectrum and NUnit packages and can't get past this error.
This thing is really unusable.

---

So I think Selenium 2.53 does not support Firefox 48.
So I have switched to Chrome.
It still runs twice but at least I am back up and running.
I hate that the console window pops up over what you are trying to look at everytime though.
Still working on the running twice thing.
Will post answer if I find.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code.

Comment: What part of the code do you want to see?
I don't think it's the actual test. Do you want to see plumbing for setup?

Comment: I apologize, I didn't mean to come across poorly. I just thought some more information may help to diagnose the issue you are experiencing. Could you please provide the version of Selenium and Firefox you are using. Also, have you tried Chromedriver to see if you get a similar result?

Comment: What version of NUnit are you on? Have you attempted to locate the NUnit Adapter Nuget package for update, or uninstall?

Comment: Sorry Miah - such a long day trying to deploy last night.  I'll start trying to fill in some of these details in the post.
Thanks!

Comment: I just upgraded Firefox from 47.1 to 48.0 and I'm getting exactly the same 'Failed to start up' error message for tests that were previously passing. Looks like the Selenium WebDriver is no longer supported and we need to use Marionette - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761668/cant-open-browser-with-selenium-after-firefox-update and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver I have not tried this yet, also note it looks like the Marionette implementation is not 100% complete.