# Selenium Webdriver opens Firefox and then dies

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have a super simple test script (below) to get started with WebDriver. When I run the test (C# - Visual Studio 2015), it opens up a Firefox browser and then does nothing.

There are several posts out there that talk about the following issue, which I'm also getting:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to start up socket within 45000 milliseconds. Attempted to connect to the following addresses: 127.0.0.1:7055.

But those posts regarding this problem are quite old and also have one major difference- their FF browser didn't open; mine does.

The error:
[image]

The code:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace seleniumDemo
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        static IWebDriver driverFF;

        [AssemblyInitialize]
        public static void SetUp(TestContext context)
        {
            driverFF = new FirefoxDriver();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestFirefoxDriver()
        {
            driverFF.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
            driverFF.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys("Selenium");
            driverFF.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
        }
    }
}
```

This question is different from what's been suggested as a duplicate because the FireFox browser actually opens in this case. In the other questions, it wasn't responding at all.

Comment: Version incompatibility most likely. Check that version of selenium you are using supports version of Firefox you have

Comment: Have look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676719/fail-to-launch-mozilla-with-selenium

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't open browser with Selenium after Firefox update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761668/cant-open-browser-with-selenium-after-firefox-update)

Comment: --> https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/8543

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be related to Selenium and Firefox version incompatibility. I also faced the same error when selenium on my machine was unable to communicate to firefox. I upgraded firefox to 46.x and it started working.

You can find version compatibility information over web or refer selenium changelog as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MarrioneteDriver` to use latest version of Firefox.

Below is the Java code, you can write in C# accordigly  (Make sure you have geckodriver.exe under BrowserDriver folder in your project folder)

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/BrowserDrivers/geckodriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        cap.setCapability("marionette", true);
        WebDriver driver = new MarionetteDriver(cap);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download latest version of `MarrioneteDriver` from below :

```
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
```

And you should Marionette executable to Windows system path :

> To add the Marionette executable to Windows system path you need
>   update the Path system variable and add the full directory to the
>   executable.
>
> To do this, right-click on the Start menu and select System. On the
>   left-side panel click Advanced system settings and then Environment
>   Variables button from System Properties window. Now the only step left
>   to do is to edit Path system variable and add the full directory to
>   your geckodriver (you may need to add a semi-colon before doing this,
>   if not already present) and you’re good to go.

Then simply create your driver instance :

```
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxOptions());
```