# Selenium Robot framework - webdriverexception : geckodriver executable needs to be in path

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, robotframework, selenium2library

could anyone help please, I have this code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***
${BROWSER}  ff
${WEBSITE}  http://www.google.com

*** Test Cases ***

Browser test
    [Documentation] Google site.
    [Tags]  Tag.
    Open Browser    ${WEBSITE}  ${BROWSER}
    Close Browser
```

I think code is correct, but i get this error: *webdriverexception message 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in path*

I have:

- Win32
- FF 47

I don't know, **how to install webdriver? How to put it to the PATH?**

- Here is no win32 version: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

I have no idea what's going on here, nowhere any guide.
 - I found only [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761668/cant-open-browser-with-selenium-after-firefox-update/37765661), but don't understand, how to install that? How set the path? A what should I do with that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know, how to install webdriver? How to put it to the PATH?

Actually now `Selenium` is supporting executable [`geckodriver.exe`](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) to launch [`Mozilla Firefox >= v47`](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/) just like other drivers.

[To work around you need to download executable `geckodriver.exe v0.8.0 for 32bit` and extract downloaded zip into your system at any location](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and set `Syetem` property with `webdriver.gecko.driver` to point with download executable geckodriver location as below :-

```
** Settings ***
Library  OperatingSystem
*** Keywords ****
Set Environment Variable  webdriver.gecko.driver  path/to/geckodriver.exe
```

Comment: Perfect, it works, thx. I only add - doesn't work with Selenium 3.

Comment: It seems this problem is often a this answer isnt the solution, so please if samobody knows to answer.

Answer (score 1):

when you use Python. the best shortcut you can do is, put you 'geckodriver.exe' file in pythons script folder. and set the Script folder path in you system path. this will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use this tool https://github.com/rasjani/webdrivermanager

Just install it in your virtualenv with

```
pip install webdrivermanager
```

and then use next command to install latest webdriver version for browser

```
webdrivermanager chrome
```