# WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, selenium

os:windows 7
selenium version 3.0.1
mozilla firefox:48.0.2

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\kk2.py", line 4, in <module>
  driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 135, in __init__
  self.service.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start
  os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
  WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

please give information step by step thoroughly please actually i am learner

Comment: same issue here...same environment...

Comment: you may downgrade your selenium by

pip install selenium==2.53.6

Comment: Worked for me as well for windows 7. I downgraded the selenium version to 2.53.6. However I could not get the reason why it is not working with selenium version 3.4.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

Answer (score 24):

For Linux based system, download [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases). Extract it and copy the driver to /usr/local/bin and finally make it executable (chmod +x geckodriver).

Answer (score 6):

please check the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37765661

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40208762

Shortly,

From selenium 3.0, you have to explicitly download `Marionette geckodriver` for Firefox (which is similar to ChromeDriver for Chrome) and keep it in a place where the system can identify it. (like System PATH - environmental variables in Windows) or specify using language options.

References:

1. [Download Marionette GeckoDriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette

Answer (score 4):

Linux(Ubuntu) Users should download the geckodriver and extract it in your project folder and while running your python script give the argument as

```
executable_path="./geckodriver"
```

*Example:*

```
from selenium import webdriver

class RunFFTests():

    def testMethod(self):
        # Initiate the driver instance
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(
            executable_path="./geckodriver")

        driver.get("http://www.letskodeit.com")

ff = RunFFTests()
ff.testMethod()
```

Comment: Above is for firefox

Answer (score 3):

For mac users use:

```
brew install geckodriver
```

Comment: This brew install helped to get over geckoDriver issue

Answer (score 3):

I just download Gecko file and paste in where your python file is. It solves the problem!

Comment: Easiest and doesn't much up your variables with junk.