# How to set up python 3.6.2 with selenium and geckodriver?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, geckodriver

Hi guys I'm in need of assistance.

So i have the latest version of python and i was able to push pip install selenium.  When i run a script it says this message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\huHMONGous\Desktop\Python 3.6\Scripts\new.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Users\huHMONGous\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 142, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\huHMONGous\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

I have windows 10.  I have downloaded geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64zip.  I extracted it and copy and paste into both user variable and system variable path and it still won't work.  Can anyone please help??  I am using notepad++ and command prompt to run my code

**Code i'm trying to run**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
```

Comment: No need to say **`Thank you`**. You say **`Thanks`** when you select the `Best` **`Answer`** as a **`Solution`** to your Question and **`Upvote`** the Answers which was **`Useful`** to you. Thanks

Comment: Duplicate, a simple Google search of the error and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40188699/webdriverexception-message-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path). Please try to search yourself before ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

When you work with `Selenium 3.4.3`, `geckodriver v0.18.0`, `Mozilla Firefox 53.0` through `Python 3.6.x` bindings you can use the following code block to open the url `https://www.youtube.com`.

Once you download and extract the `geckodriver` executable, you can keep it anywhere on your system and explicitly call them in your scripts without worrying about **copy-paste** into **`User Variable`** and **`System Variable`** path. Hence you achieve the flexibility of working with multiple versions of the `geckodriver` executable as per your requirement.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path=r'C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com')
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.