# How to use acceptSslCerts with RemoteWebdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, automation

I am trying to force selenium to ignore SSL errors, but haven't been able to figure it out. I have seen `acceptSslCerts` capability, but it does not seem to have any effect when using firefox

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, you can try something similar to this. It worked well for me on Firefox browser.

Create new firefox profile by following below step and accept SSL certificates there.

1. Close all your firefox windows
2. In the Run dialog box, type in: ‘firefox.exe -p' and then Click OK.
3. Click “Create Profile”
4. Create a name for your new profile(say Selenium)
5. Click “Choose Folder”
6. Pick something easy to find — like “C:\NewFirefoxProfile”
7. Click Finish
8. Now after selecting newly created profile, start Firefox. Open the specific url you were getting 'Secure Connection Issue', accept SSL certificates for this profile

[image]

Now use the newly created firefox profile to run your selenium test. Modify below code as per your requirement.

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
profile.assume_untrusted_cert_issuer=True

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile='C:/NewFirefoxProfile)
driver.get('https://cacert.org/')
```