# Why Selenium stops after login to a page ?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, testing, selenium-webdriver

We have successfully login into the application via Selenium, but we can´t go anywhere from there.

Selenium just stop working from that point on.

This is the code that we are using to get into the application:

```
public class testclass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Selenium-java-3.0.1\\geckodriver.exe");
    ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
       // this will create an object for the Firefox profile
    FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("default");
       // this will Initialize the Firefox driver
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
     driver.get("https://applicationURL/Forms");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login']")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login']")).sendKeys("username");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("password");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='btnlogin']")).click();
```

[this is where Selenium just stops]

```
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='panelBarMiddleSearchPanels_i0_txtAttr_1_22']")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='panelBarMiddleSearchPanels_i0_txtAttr_1_22']")).sendKeys("LTR*");

}
```

}

Then I don`t know where to find the error that Selenium is getting ? Because it just stops at the point where it needs to go further.

I am not sure if it is important to mention, but we are working via VPN. I am not sure if it is related to this issue -- [Can't open browser with Selenium after Firefox update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761668/cant-open-browser-with-selenium-after-firefox-update)

Comment: Can you post a stack trace of the error you are getting? is it possible that the element is not loaded yet? can you add in a wait for the page to load after the login

Comment: @NebojsaKomnenovic IMHO, you should immediately stop loading the `default` profile and start your Automation work with a new Profile created either afresh manually or created on the fly. With the default profile you seem to be lucky getting till that point :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use following updated code :

```
   public class testclass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Selenium-java-3.0.1\\geckodriver.exe");
    ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
       // this will create an object for the Firefox profile
    FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("default");
       // this will Initialize the Firefox driver
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
     driver.get("https://applicationURL/Forms");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login']")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login']")).sendKeys("username");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("password");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='btnlogin']")).click();
     Thread.sleep(7000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='panelBarMiddleSearchPanels_i0_txtAttr_1_22']")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='panelBarMiddleSearchPanels_i0_txtAttr_1_22']")).sendKeys("LTR*");

}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Using `Thread.sleep(7000);` reduces performance of the executing thread. Avoid using `Thread.sleep();` and suggesting `Thread.sleep();` Thanks